How to optimize a SQL query to get a user and their total order count?
I have typical Users and Orders tables:
CREATE TABLE Users 
(
    id INT, 
    name TEXT 
);

CREATE TABLE Orders 
(
    id INT, 
    name TEXT, 
    userId REFERENCES Users(id) 
);

I want a query to get a count of all orders belonging to a specific user's name ("bob"). e.g.,



User(id)
User(name)
Count(Orders)




1
Bob
150



I have 2 possible queries:
SELECT * 
FROM Users
JOIN 
    (SELECT Bob.id, COUNT(*)
     FROM Orders
     JOIN  
         (SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name = 'bob') Bob ON Orders.userId = Bob.id
     GROUP BY Bob.id) BobOrders ON BobOrders.id = Users.id;

Using EXPLAIN ANALYZE returns: Planning Time: 0.301 ms / Execution Time: 0.170 ms
Another shorter but unoptimized query is:
SELECT * 
FROM Users
JOIN 
    (SELECT userId, COUNT(*) 
     FROM Orders 
     GROUP BY userId) MyData ON MyData.userId = Users.id 
                             AND Users.name = 'bob';

Using EXPLAIN ANALYZE returns: Planning Time: 0.172 ms / Execution Time: 0.106 ms
Why does the query analyzer say the 2nd query is faster when it needs to GROUP BY the whole orders list before filtering by Users.id?

Why should I "tag my RDBMS"? - please add a tag to specify whether you're using mysql, postgresql, sql-server, oracle or db2 - or something else entirely.

How big are these user and order tables?

Why not simple LEFT JOIN? https://sqlize.online/s/aN

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result.

I wonder why you chose to use subqueries at all? Why not simply do it like this:
SELECT u.id, u.name, count(*) 
FROM Users u JOIN Orders o ON (o.userId=u.id)
WHERE u.name = 'Bob'
GROUP BY (u.id, u.name);

What does explain say to this?
Further if you are only interested in the count of exactly one user, you could also skip the group by clause and only return count(*) (assuming you use the user id rather than the name to avoid, e.g. multiple different Bobs)
